# Can an AI have awareness?

Tags: philosophy, agi, artificial-consciousness, imagination

I was thinking about the following:

According to Sir Roger Penrose "No computer has any awareness of what it does.".

Now some context to his statement:

Penrose’s argument in summary in his book (The emperor's new mind: concerning computers, minds, and the laws of physics) is that:

- We don’t understand physics well enough to use it to describe our brains.
- We don’t understand the mind well enough to create a framework capable of accommodating human consciousness.
- Since our minds do not operate ‘computationally’ and are non-algorithmic, our intelligence, therefore, can’t be recreated by computers ([Source](https://projectqsydney.com/roger-penrose-versus-the-world/)).

Let's look at the latest controversy started by a Google engineer who claimed that `Lambda` is self aware. But, then I came across Searle’s Chinese Room and realized that Lambda is not self aware.

[image]

Then there are other self learning AIs like `OpenAIFive` that was really good in playing DOTA2.

But how do we know this AI understands what it's doing? If not then is there a possibility that a hypothetical AGI in future might be aware of its actions?

As a note I will add that the brain is still a big mystery and there's no unanimous  consensus on a single definition of consciousness. And I think every definition out there is just a combination of thought and faith/belief. And Penrose as of lately does however thinks that there might be a connection between consciousness and quantum mechanics.

Answer (score -3):

Are kids conscious?

I always say that if a human can do it, and AI will be able to do it. There is nothing special to us: no magic, no soul. We will eventually crack intelligence. I personally don't even bother with the term "conscious". It doesn't mean much.

Comment: Whilst I agree with the sentiment, this answer doesn't really engage with the question as asked. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, and we're not looking for opinions.

Comment: @NeilSlater Aren't you asking in the wrong place then?

Comment: I am not asking anything. The OP has given references that they are trying to understand and resolve, and a good answer would reference and/or address them, or bring up equivalent references that the OP could use to understand the subject further. This answer so far expresses a personal opinion. I don't disagree with it, but I think it is not a good quality answer for our site in its current form.

Comment: You are assuming functionalism. So this answer is just an opinion. I know this is an extremely popular viewpoint, especially among scientists, but you shouldn't make the mistake to think somehow that it's a "proven fact" or anything of the sorts.